# jQuery Mobile 1.2 Data-Icon "Edit" not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="edit">hello</a>
```

This button just displays with a Plus icon instead of the edit icon, anyone know why? I'm using jquery mobile, here is my header:

```
  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try data-role="button" as an attribute, they have it in the docs.

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong button code there, amended now, this has the same issue, shows plus icon

Comment: you can see it here: http://www.bbwebmessenger.com/mobile1582/

Comment: Okay so currently the issue is only with the data-icon="edit".. other icons like "arrow-l" work...

Comment: Yeah other icons work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something's wrong with their CSS, as I just tried this locally. Here's a fix:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon-edit {
        background-image: url(icons-18-white.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: -824px 50%;
    }
</style>
```

Either amend your own style sheet to add this or place this in your `<head></head>` below the rest of your CSS. Also you'll need to grab your own icons-18-white.png from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/images/icons-18-white.png) and save it locally.

---

**To get the edit button working:**

First, **[download icons-18-white.png](http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/images/icons-18-white.png)** and save it in the same folder as your webpage.

Then, just copy and paste this code and continue from there.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon-edit {
        background-image: url(icons-18-white.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: -824px 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="edit">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im not sure if i have done this right but i added that style to the head and now i get a gray circle: http://www.bbwebmessenger.com/mobile1582/

Comment: You also need to download icons-18-white.png and place it locally (because background-image in the CSS above uses this).

Answer (score 3):

The edit icon was only introduced a month ago to be included in 1.3.  It's not a bug with 1.2 it just wasn't included.

See blog post for more information: 
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/01/14/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-0-beta/

Comment: I'll upvote this, definitely want to bear that in mind until 1.3 comes out. Either way, perhaps OP should rename question to include jQuery Mobile version for future searchers?

Answer (score 0):

data-icon="edit" is available since jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 
So you`d better use that version.

More information here - http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/04/10/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/